# Queueuserworkitem vs TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback

Tags: c++, winapi, threadpool, iocp

### Main Question:

What is the difference between QueueUserWorkItem and TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback given that they both queue a work item to the Thread Pool

---

***TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback***

> This function adds a work item to the thread pool's queue (by calling
> PostQueuedCompletionStatus) and returns TRUE if successful; it returns
> FALSE if unsuccessful.

> In some circumstances, such as lack of memory or quota limitations, the call to TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback might
> fail. Each time you call TrySubmitThreadpoolCallback, internally a work item is allocated on your behalf.

Reference: https://www.amazon.com.br/Windows-Via-C-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735663777

***QueueUserWorkItem***

> Queues a method for execution where the method executes when the thread is active.

Reference: https://www.macoratti.net/09/06/vb_patp.htm

---

As I understand it, both functions do exactly the same thing, is the difference related to compatibility or something along these lines?

If not, what is the difference between the two?

in addition, if the answer is no, I would like that it is specified the characteristics of each one if possible.

---

### WAIT !

If my question is incomplete, or is formatted in an inappropriate way, please comment so I can adjust it, thank you in advance, in advance.

Lucas P.

Comment: this api not exactly the same. callbacks signature also different. exist also `SubmitThreadpoolWork` which very near. `QueueUserWorkItem` can queue item only to default pool, when another to api - and in another pool too. but in general - yes, all 3 api basically do almost same thing - let post work item to pool. `QueueUserWorkItem` more old api.

Comment: `QueueUserWorkItem` is from the legacy threadpool API.  The newer function gives you more control over the environement in which the callback is executed by virtue of permitting you to initialize an environment for the callback (via `InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment`).  In my experience, when MS starts calling something "legacy" and I have a choice, I find it is usually better to go with the API that is not "legacy"

Comment: Got it, I didn't know the possibility of using the InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment, I discovered that it is possible to configure the minimum/maximum number of default threads and other configurations with this additional parameter (in the new APIs).

For this reason I thought that both functions were the same, that is, because I was unaware of this possibility, I thank them both (@Joe and
@RbMm).

Anyway, I'll finish the research, but thanks for responding.

Comment: Please post an answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: OK posted as an answer.  But in fairness I only answered your question by comparing them in the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueueUserWorkItem` is from the legacy threadpool API. The newer function gives you more control over the environment in which the callback is executed by virtue of permitting you to initialize an environment for the callback (via `InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment`). In my experience, when MS starts calling something "legacy" and I have a choice, I find it is usually better to go with the API that is not "legacy"